# Disable the full_page cache for a specific controller

Tags: controllers, full-page-cache

I have a controller that I want to exclude from the full page cache however want to cache the block rendered within the controller.

I have tried the below code however this does not seem to work:

```
protected function getCacheLifetime(){
    return null;
}
```

The full page cache continued with this.

I have also tried:

```
$this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));
```

This however throws an error about undefined method `addData()`

I do not want to disable within layouts as this will disable the cache for the block. My block caching works fine and caches for however long I define.